# Song capacity of 1st Gen iPod

Tags: ipod

I had downloaded several songs on my iPod about 2 years ago. I purchased more and downloaded them, but realized many of the original downloads were missing. I tired to download again and it doesn't work. Is there a limit for songs/albums? They are all on my laptop as purchased. I only use it at the gym, but would like to have more choices.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Here you can see the capacity in GB and how many songs are estimated for the original iPod.  See linked source below for other models.

> [image]
>
> * Apple estimated the song capacity of the first and second generation iPod using the 160-Kbps MP3 format. These files are larger than the
>   128-Kbps AAC format used to estimate the capacity of subsequent iPod
>   models.

Information taken from: [How many songs does each iPod, iPod mini, iPod nano, iPod touch, and iPod shuffle hold?](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipod/ipod-faq/how-many-songs-does-ipod-hold-capacity.html)

Comment: I edited your answer because link only answers are frowned upon and are sometimes down-voted and possibly removed altogether.

Answer (score 3):

The first answer answers the question you had about the song capacity of a 1st generation iPod, but I thought I'd offer some additional info as I think the capacity is only part of the answer to your problem.

Purchasing more songs and syncing them to your iPod would not normally remove the original songs. Syncing can be a little confusing at times, so it's likely that at some point you chose for them to be removed without realising it.

Your best bet is to connect your iPod to your laptop and use iTunes to determine how much space you actually have left? This will give you an indication as to whether you can just re-select the original songs and have them transferred (synced) to your iPod or whether you have a space management issue.

If you've run out of space it's just a case of removing some songs to make room for the ones you want.

If you already have the space then you need to work out why you couldn't transfer the songs you wanted. This is where coming back here and asking another question about how to resolve the issue (if you can't find a solution) is probably the way to go. If so, be sure to identify what version of iTunes you're using and what version of Mac OS X or Windows your computer is running. Perhaps even include a screenshot or two of how iTunes looks when you have your iPod connected.

Either way I hope you resolve your issue. Good luck!